# "3706 provider not found"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-connection, ms-access-2007

I am working on a project in VB.NET (actually I have migrated the code from VB6) and I am getting the error `3706 provider not found`.

Here is the code:

```
gcnnSpectraHost = New ADODB.Connection
gcnnSpectraHost.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
gcnnSpectraHost.Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
gcnnSpectraHost.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\SpectraHost1p011.mdb;")
gcnnSpectraHost.ConnectionString = gstrDBFileName
gcnnSpectraHost.Open()
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be mixing a few things together.

```
gcnnSpectraHost = New ADODB.Connection
gcnnSpectraHost.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
```

Either

```
gcnnSpectraHost.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\SpectraHost1p011.mdb;"
gcnnSpectraHost.Open()
```

Or

```
gcnnSpectraHost.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\SpectraHost1p011.mdb;")
```

Not needed

```
'gcnnSpectraHost.ConnectionString = gstrDBFileName
'gcnnSpectraHost.Open()
```

See : http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007